# Get the same coordinates for points after downloading a .osm file

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-2

I downloaded a .kml file that contains bike stations which I know the coordinates (latitude and longitude). So I got a layer that contains points corresponding to the stations. Then I downloaded the data to a  .osm file.

My problem is that the coordinates of the points (latitude and longitude) have changed in the .osm file, I can not distinguish the coordinates of  bike stations in this file knowing that the CRS used in QGIS is WGS 84; EPSG: 4326.

Why when downloading  the layer to .osm file QGIS changes the coordinates of the points?
What should I do to keep the same coordinates after downloading a .osm file please?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail where the KML is from and where the OSM file is from? What exactly are the steps you are using in QGIS? What do you expect? What exactly is the issue? Maybe add a screenshot for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Form your images (which should be added to the question, and not posted as an answer), you seem to download bicyle stations from http://data.grandlyon.com/equipements/station-vflov-disponibilitfs-temps-rfel/

Besides kml, they offer the data in shapefile format. This is the preferred format for GIS software, and you can choose the CRS you want (EPSG:4326).

To download the same data in Openstreetmap, use the `QuickOSM` plugin, querying for Key `amenity` and Value `bicycle_rental`, on the extent of the points layer.

You will get almost the same points, but they are not 100% on the same spot. Just because Openstreetmap uses people going outside and looking where exactly the rental station is, while the town may have less exact data about the location. To identify the stations, you can match the `number` field from data grandlyon and the `ref` field from Openstreetmap:

[image]

This works better than the `name` fields, which are different in some cases.